# How can I link CMake and SQLite without an external script?

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake

I have the following CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (Tutorial)
find_package (sqlite3)
if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries (new ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)
add_executable(Tutorial new.cpp)
```

However, when I cmake, I get the following message:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findsqlite3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "sqlite3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sqlite3" with any
  of the following names:

    sqlite3Config.cmake
    sqlite3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "sqlite3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I have also tried [this](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake) and [this](https://github.com/alex85k/sqlite3-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) for alternative CMakeLists files, but none of these have worked.

I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
FIND_PATH(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES sqlite3.h)
FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY NAMES sqlite)
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SQLITE3 DEFAULT_MSG SQLITE3_LIBRARY SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
IF(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES ${SQLITE3_LIBRARY})
    SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSE(SQLITE3_FOUND)
    SET(SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
    SET(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
ENDIF(SQLITE3_FOUND)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS SQLITE3_LIBRARIES)
```

How can I link SQLite without using an extension?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have basically two options:
1) have a `FindSQLite3.cmake` in a directory called `cmake` inside your project's root directory like the following [FindSQLite3.cmake](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake)
that you already tried but you need to have something like the following

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (Tutorial)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
add_executable(tutorial new.cpp)
find_package (SQLite3)
if (SQLITE3_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries (tutorial ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
endif (SQLITE3_FOUND)
```

2) since you know the location of your sqlite3 include directory and library you could directly set the path to those, in your `CMakeLists.txt` you will have something like `link_directories()` and `include_directories()`, e.g. you will have the following lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (Tutorial)
add_executable(tutorial new.cpp)
include_directories(/usr/include)
link_directories(/usr/lib)
target_link_libraries(tutorial sqlite3)
```

Something along those two directions should work.
Personally, I would suggest the first approach.

Comment: if you use the linked FindSQLite3.cmake, change the FIND_LIBRARY as follow, otherwis eit will not find libsqlite3 :`# Look for the library.
FIND_LIBRARY(SQLITE3_LIBRARY NAMES sqlite3)`

Answer (score 6):

I just added the following sting to my **CMakeLists.txt** file and it works.

```
find_package (SQLite3)

include_directories(${SQLite3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (${OUT_TARGET} ${SQLite3_LIBRARIES})
```

*cmake version 3.14.3*

Comment: Do not use variables directly, link to target instead: `target_link_libraries (${OUT_TARGET} SQLite3::SQLite3)`

Comment: @valsaysReinstateMonica Could you elaborate more why linking to target is better? Or could you point me to the resource where I can read about that topic?

Comment: @IgNite For once, you're now specifying what you're depending on in a single place (includes/library files and defines of a library can hardly be separated logically), it's easier to switch between prebuilt library and building it with your project and it's generally a modern way in CMake. You also can take a look at https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/.