# Sqlite amalgamation C file doesn't compile on Raspbian

Tags: c, sqlite, raspbian

I am using a Raspberry Pi to run a C program that interacts with a can interface, and stores values in a database as part of a project.
I started C one month ago, and I am still a bit lost with everything.

## Description of my workspace and problem :

I have my test file `test virtual.c` that includes a homemade file `handler_code.c` that includes the `sqlite3.c` amalgamation file(via `#include "sqlite3.c"`).
Then I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that was provided to me :

```
if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
    set( STANDALONE TRUE )
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
    set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    find_package(CARLOS REQUIRED)
else()
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/core/include)
    include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/gui/include)
endif()

add_definitions(-DRESOURCES_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources")

add_executable(test_example "test virtual.c")
target_link_libraries(test_example carlos)

set_target_properties(
    test_example
    PROPERTIES
    C_STANDARD 99
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/examples_bin
)
```

It imports all libraries I need. All the files are in the same directory.
I then go in the subdirectory `build` and run `cmake ..` which succeeds and then `make`. This is what happens :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/examples/build $ make
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_example.dir/test_virtual.c.o
In file included from /home/pi/Desktop/examples/handler_code.c:5,
                 from /home/pi/Desktop/examples/test virtual.c:8:
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c:34058:42: error: ‘mremap’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘munmap’?
   { "mremap",       (sqlite3_syscall_ptr)mremap,          0 },
                                          ^~~~~~
                                          munmap
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c: In function ‘unixRemapfile’:
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c:38625:42: error: ‘MREMAP_MAYMOVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     pNew = osMremap(pOrig, nReuse, nNew, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c:38625:42: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c:38625:42: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘(void * (*)(void *, size_t,  size_t,  int,  ...))aSyscall[24].pCurrent’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
/home/pi/Desktop/examples/sqlite3.c:38625:42: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct unix_syscall *’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_example.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/test_example.dir/test_virtual.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/test_example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I tried only compiling `sqlite3.c` with gcc and I got this :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/examples $ gcc sqlite3.c
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `pthreadMutexAlloc':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x5098): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/bin/ld: sqlite3.c:(.text+0x50a8): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/bin/ld: sqlite3.c:(.text+0x50c8): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `pthreadMutexTry':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x51b8): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `sqlite3ThreadCreate':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x9fcc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `sqlite3ThreadJoin':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0xa084): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `unixDlOpen':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x148c0): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `unixDlError':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x148f4): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `unixDlSym':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x14970): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6Quw7S.o: in function `unixDlClose':
sqlite3.c:(.text+0x1498c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also did some tests on my windows computer. The file named `config.c` includes the amalgamation just like `handler_code.c` did.

```
PS C:\Users\p107770\Desktop\projects\hmi-rapid-prototyping\C> gcc sqlite3.c
C:/MATLAB/V_R2016b/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\p107770\Desktop\projects\hmi-rapid-prototyping\C> gcc config.c
PS C:\Users\p107770\Desktop\projects\hmi-rapid-prototyping\C>
```

So here, it successfully compiles the file that includes the amalgamation file (which is what I'd want on my raspberry pi, even though it's not the same file), but it does not compile the amalgamation file alone (which I don't understand).

## Ideas I found while searching

#### Using sqlite as a library/package in CMake file

Something looking like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640029/how-can-i-link-cmake-and-sqlite-without-an-external-script/41642102). But looking at my CMake file, I realized that my sqlite amalgamation file was not a "package" in the same way `CARLOS` and `Threads` are (I installed CARLOS with .deb files provided to me). So my question here is how to transform the amalgamtion file into a package ?

#### Compiling sqlite so it would be imported globally

I remember reading something about this. If I recall correctly, I can compile the sqlite amalgamation file into a .dll and make it available in any C file with the `#include <sqlite3.c>` line instead of `#include "sqlite3.c"`, but I don't know if it would work here because I think this was working when compiling with gcc and not with make.

Thank you in advance for any help you could bring, I can add bits of code if needed.

Comment: Add `-pthread` when compiling `sqlite3.c`

Comment: I'm sure Raspbian has sqlite3-dev package so you can just get pre-built SQLite and link with it using `-lsqlite3`

Comment: @qrdl Better to include sqlite directly in a C program that uses it. It'll usually be a newer version, and you can pick and choose the features and extensions you need instead of hoping they're in whatever random build the OS provides.

Comment: @qrdl where am i supposed to put -sqlite3 ? do I have to change the include statements ?

Comment: But anyways, sqlite3.c should be compiled as a separate file, not included in another one.

Comment: @MorganLugagne Like with any library, you add `-lsqlite3` to `gcc` command line