# compiling c++ project with sqlite3 through cmake

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, c++14

So I'm working on a university project and I decided I wanted to add a database (we have to make a game that runs on the console). I'm currently using GitHub Codespaces, so basically VSCode running on Linux.

After a lot of struggling I managed to get cmake to work with my project as well as include Catch2 in the project but now I was trying to add a database to the game as well. The only issue is non of the tutorials/guides/troubleshooting posts I've looked into seem to work. I've tried to configure it in multiple ways but it always gives a different error which seems as unsolvable as the previous.

In case you're wondering GitHub Codespaces already comes with pretty much everything, I used installation commands like `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` but it didn't change anything (0 packages installed/changed) as it already contains sqlite

This is my file structure (some changes have been made along the way to the sqlite as I have been trying things around):

```
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
| debug
--| Catch2
--| CMakeFiles
--| sqlite
  --| include (contains sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h and all the amalgamation files)
  --| lib (contains the linux files: "sqldiff", "sqlite3" and "sqlite3_analyzer")
| include (all my header files)
| src (all my .cpp files except for main.cpp)
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

# define libraries to link to final executable
set (PROJECT_LINK_LIBS sqlite3.dll)
# define the sqlite header include file directory
set (SQLITE_INCLUDE debug/sqlite/include)
# define the sqlite link library directory
set (SQLITE_LINK_DIR debug/sqlite/lib)

#Project file name and version
project(game VERSION 0.1)

#Project compilation
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES src/*.cpp)
add_executable(game main.cpp ${SRC_FILES} debug/sqlite3/include/sqlite3.c)
include_directories(game PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

#SQLite integration

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
# define the directories to search for libraries
link_directories ( ${SQLITE_LINK_DIR})
# define the directories to search for headers
include_directories (include ${SQLITE_INCLUDE})
# define the libraries to link to the final executable
target_link_libraries (game ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(game PUBLIC sqlite3)

#include_directories( /usr/local/lib )
#find_package ( sqlite3  REQUIRED /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so)
#add_compile_options(-l sqlite3)
#if(SQLITE3_FOUND)
#    include_directories(${SQLite3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#    target_link_libraries(${OUT_TARGET} ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
#endif(SQLITE3_FOUND)
#include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug/sqlite3/)
#set(sqlite3_srcs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug/sqlite3/sqlite3.c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug/sqlite3/sqlite3.h )
#add_library(sqlitelib SHARED ${sqlite3_srcs} )
#target_link_libraries(game sqlitelib)
```

There are plenty of things commented out as they didn't work and I eventually tried different things.

I usually get errors either by running "cmake .." from debug like `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sqlite3" with any of the following names` or when I manage to get that part to work it gets errors at compilation like `` main.cpp.o: in function \main': main.cpp (.text+0x31e): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'` `` with a bunch of others that don't seem to be recognized even though I'm using #include <sqlite.h> in the main.cpp

I've tried multiple things that I found on google but honestly non of them worked. Any help would be appreciated

I've googled, looked into multiple posts on stackoverflow and other webpages. None of them really helped out.

I want to be able to compile my project that uses sqlite3 using cmake

Comment: Using SQLite with CMake is described e.g. in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640029/how-can-i-link-cmake-and-sqlite-without-an-external-script). "... undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'` with a bunch of others that don't seem to be recognized even though I'm using #include <sqlite.h> in the main.cpp" - The error "undefined reference" is absolutely unrelated to the inclusion of the header. This error is resolved by proper linkage (with `target_link_libraries` command).

Comment: @Tsyvarev that question in particular is one of the many posts I've found, and I have tried to used. I've tried both suggestions from the answer that got marked as the answer and even checked a few of the other replies but I still have the same error anyway

Answer (score 2):

Why folks do crazy things in their CMakeLists?

Since 3.14 CMake comes with a `FindSQLite3.cmake` module file: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSQLite3.html

So it's quite simple since libsqlite3-dev package is installed on your system:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSON 3.14)
project(foobar)

find_package(SQLite3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE SQLite::SQLite3)
```

Comment: They _are_ using `find_package`: "`find_package(unofficial-sqlite3`". I have no idea what the difference between what they `find_package` and what you suggest here is though.

Comment: `find_package(unofficial-sqlite3` refers to what? Some mysterious find module or config file nobody knows? `find_package(SQLite3` refers to an official Find module file.